# Java multiple threads accessing one String

Tags: java, swing

I have a one String which will be access by four different threads in unpredicatable order.

```
String s = "When value is";
```

Now above string s will be updated by four different threads through Java Swing EDT. I have two JCombobox and two JTextField. Inside event handler of these components I will have to update above string.

For e.g.
when textfield focus changes string should be "When value is X"
when combo changes string should be "When value is less than X and Y"

So like above four thread will be changing one string. If I dont control them output is unexpected. What is the best way to solve this. I can use join() or may go for volatile but it will make code complex.

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this value is changed because of GUI events, I see no race condition.  The value will depend on the event that triggers last.

Comment: There is only one thread in the Swing EDT. Why do you have four threads?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java.

Comment: @Peter I agree, only one EDT thread but there are four event handlers which gets executed in unpredictable order. So I want to control them. Sometimes on thread is ahead because of user input and so on.

Comment: can you show us your `FocusListener` added to your `textfield`

Comment: @Umesh the event handlers are executed on the Swing EDT.  It does not quite matter that they are called in unpredictable manner.

Comment: @user unknown. We don't care if String are mutable or not. It is the reference that will be updated, not the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, a `String` is immutable so it cannot be updated. Another object, such as a Swing component, may however hold a reference to a `String`, and this reference can be updated to point to a different `String`. This is what normally happens when text is updated in a GUI.

If you have four different threads that need to update a Swing component, e.g. to display a different `String`, they should do it by queuing a task to be run on the single Event Dispatching Thread using the `SwingUtilities` methods `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`, e.g.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myComponent.setText("New string");
  }
};
```

Or in a more sophisticated application you might want to update a domain object, which would then need to be thread safe, from each of these four threads, and then separately update the Swing component on the EDT. Creating thread-safe code is not easy, in my opinion. I highly recommend the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), but the main point is to ensure that only one thread at a time carries out any operation that involves the object in question being temporarily in an inconsistent state. This is sometimes possible by suitable use of existing thread-safe classes and atomic operations, but may require the use of a lock, typically through `synchronized` methods or blocks.

Of course, none of this is relevant if, as it now appears, you do not have four threads at all but only four event handlers called on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, there is only one event dispatch thread. Unless you are using Swing improperly (and *Ben*'s answer speaks to that), your real problem is that you don't know the order in which events will be fired.

There is no way to control this order, even for a single component. Trying to use *join* or some form of locking mechanism will just hang your application.

The solution is to create an object that mediates between the input sources. Based on your description, this could be a simple `Map<String,String>`, where the key is the event source and the value is whatever you ultimately want to display.

Your action listeners each add a value to this map, and when the 4th value is added you decide which value should be written to the output.

Then you clear the map, waiting for the next set of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your program with the assumption that order the events are processed is the correct order.

Lets suppose for a moment, you want multiple events to the same field and the order is really important. However, you don't trust the EDT notify the events in the order you need them to be. Can you demonstrate an example of where the order would be incorrect and how you intend to correct for it?